# Como obter a screen density no Android via código?

Tags: java, android

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação aonde as imagens e os layouts se adaptam de acordo com a densidade lógica do dispositivo.

É possível obter a screen dpi do dispositivo através do Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível obter a densidade lógica através do código

```
 getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

Ele irá te retornar:

0.75 - ldpi (baixa resolução)

1.0 - mdpi (média resolução)

1.5 - hdpi (alta resolução)

2.0 - xhdpi (ótima resolução)

3.0 - xxhdpi (+ótima resolução)

4.0 - xxxhdpi (excelente)

[image]

[referência: density](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#density)

Comment: "Densidade em pixels da tela" dá a impressão que são pixels físicos, o que não é o caso. O termo usado na documentação é "densidade lógica". E uma forma mais precisa de dizer seria "A relação aproximada entre um `dip` (_density-independent pixel_) e um pixel físico". Nem chega a ser relação exata porque serve apenas para agrupar as densidades em _buckets_ ou grupos (`ldpi`, `mdpi`, `hdpi`, etc.). Para obter a densidade exata o cálculo é mais complicado.

Comment: Obrigado @Piovezan, editei a resposta.