# ANDROID: Como identificar a densidade da tela do usuário?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Quero que o aplicativo faço apenas o download das imagens que são adaptáveis a tela do usuário, como por exemplo: se o dispositivo do usuário der suporte a imagens xxhdpi, não será necessário armazenar as imagens de xxxhdpi, mdpi, hdpi, e por ai vai...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Os qualificadores citados são densidades, onde `mdpi` é o *baseline*. E os demais são proporcionais ao `mdpi`.

Isso é:

- ldpi = 0.75 * mdpi
- hdpi = 1.5 * mdpi
- xhdpi = 2.0 * mdpi
- xxhdpi = 3.0 * mdpi
- xxxhdpi = 4.0 * mdpi

Programaticamente é possível identificar qual a densidade de tela do aparelho, basta usar:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
Activity activity = <Sua Activity>;
activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

int density = metrics.densityDpi; // Densidade (ldpi, mdpi e etc...)
```

O resultado de `density` é um dos valores abaixo:

```
DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW (ldpi)
DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM (mdpi)
DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH (hdpi)
DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH (xhdpi)
DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH (xxhpi)
DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH (xxxhdpi)
```

Uma abordagem simples para o download seria combinar a densidade para montar ou selecionar uma url (de uma coleção de urls) de imagem para cada densidade e buscar conforme o resultado do aparelho.

**Obs**: Lembrando que densidade não é igual a tamanho de tela. Na teoria, podemos ter dispositivos com densidade de 640dpi (xxxhdpi) com resolução de 320x240 e um outro dispositivo com 120dpi e resolução 1920x1080.

Mas densidade é uma métrica legal para filtrar imagens. Uma métrica mais real, porém bem mais complicada seria combinar as demensões de tela com a densidade.

Comment: Muito obrigado @Wakim!!

Answer (score 1):

É possível obter a densidade lógica através do código

```
 getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

Ele irá te retornar:

0.75 - ldpi (baixa resolução)

1.0 - mdpi (média resolução)

1.5 - hdpi (alta resolução)

2.0 - xhdpi (ótima resolução)

3.0 - xxhdpi (+ótima resolução)

4.0 - xxxhdpi (excelente)

[image]

[referência: density](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#density)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode descobrir qual é a categoria de densidade (*density bucket*) a que o dispositivo pertence através [desta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/82419/como-obter-a-screen-density-no-android-via-c%C3%B3digo) ou pela resposta do @Wakim, depois passar essa informação como parâmetro para a requisição ao webservice que vai trazer a imagem apropriada (informada também como parâmetro).